# Highcharter R bubbleLegend doesn't work when the x-axis is categorical

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I'm currently trying to create a Highcharts scatter plot that displays a bubble legend when the second variable is selected. When the second variable is selected, I add the size parameter to the hc_add_series(..., hcaes(size = var2)) function.

The issue is, when the first variable is a categorical/factor etc, then the plot renders incorrectly. The x-axis labels and points on the graph are all pushed to the left of the plot. It works as expected without the bubbleLegend enabled AND it works when the second variable isn't a categorial.

Since the app I'm actually working on is quite large, I've recreated the issue with some dummy code in a basic shiny app. This is my first question on SO, so please let me know if I need to provide more info. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

temp = as.data.table(iris)
choices = names(temp)[-1]

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(class="row",
      column(width = 3, fixedPanel(
          selectInput("in_var1","Select Grouping Variable 1:",
                      choices = choices,
                      selected = choices[4],
                      multiple = FALSE),
          selectInput("in_var2","Select Size Variable:",
                      choices =  c("\a", choices),
                      selected = NULL,
                      multiple = FALSE),
        width = "20%"
      )),
      column(width = 9,
             highchartOutput("scatter_plot",height = "500px"),
      ))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  explore_scatterplot = function(data, var1, var2=NULL){
    in_data = copy(data)
    in_data[, var1 := get(var1)]
    if(var2 != "\a"){ in_data[, var2 := get(var2)]}
    
    # init hc object
    scp = highchart() %>%
      hc_yAxis(min = 0)
    
    if(var1 == "Species") {
      scp = scp %>% hc_xAxis(type = "category")
      in_data = in_data[order(var1)]
    }
    
    # build the plot based on which variables are selected
    if(var2 == "\a"){
      scp = scp %>%
        hc_add_series(data = in_data, hcaes(x = var1, y = Sepal.Length), type = "scatter", showInLegend = FALSE)
    } else {
      scp = scp %>%
        hc_add_series(data = in_data, hcaes(x = var1, y = Sepal.Length, size = var2), type = "scatter", 
                      maxSize = "10%", showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
        hc_legend(bubbleLegend = list(enabled = TRUE))
    }
    
    return(scp)
  }
  
  output$scatter_plot <- renderHighchart({
    validate(need(!is.null(input$in_var1) &
                  !is.null(input$in_var2), "Waiting on inputs..."))
    
    scp = explore_scatterplot(data = temp,
                              var1 = input$in_var1, 
                              var2 = input$in_var2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: A scatterplot is not meant to display both nominal and ratio (words and numbers). A scatterplot is designed for numbers. When you get the working plot with `Species` on the y-axis, it's because `highcharter` has set one axis to the row number (starting at zero) and the other axis to the variable selected. To combine a category and a number field, you could use a circle packing diagram AKA bubble chart - or as `highcharter` named it, a packed bubble chart (`"packedbubble"` in the function). I can work the code if you'd like.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info! A "packedbubble" chart doesn't work for my situation but I found a work around. I set the categories of hc_xAxis to be levels("Species") and then converted "Species" to a numeric which seemed to do the trick.
***
    `if(var1 == "Species") {
      scp = scp %>% hc_xAxis(type = "category", categories = levels(in_data$var1))
      in_data = in_data[,var1 := as.numeric(var1) - 1][order(var1)]
    }`